# Django: /logout switches language

Tags: django, django-authentication

I know this is going to sound silly but I can't find what's wrong.
I am using the built in views for user auth and logging in and loggin out respectively switches the language to the non default language for the current session.

I have two languages, setup according to documentation on Djangoproject site i.e. in locale folder and there are .mo files and everything. Fine.

I have a form based language switch that enables language switch for any user that posts to /i18n/setlang

So, my question is, how come it seems to "POST" to switch language when I do a logout or a login (which I guess are both POST's as well).

Thanks for shedding any light possible on this.

EDIT: I should add that it never switches back. It only switches languages in one direction i.e. to the language that is not default.

EDIT2: Not that I think it will attract any more answers but here's the code for my language switcher (it switches on the fly via jQuery. The problems is STILL that it goes to Deutch language and stays there whenever I logout (logout is handled by the logout view in Django).

```
<ul>            
    <li>
        <form name="setLangen" action="/i18n/setlang/" method="POST"><div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='871Y71JyfG9WcieiKr8jjwe4j37IkIfq' /></div>
        <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/" />
        <input type="hidden" name="language" value="en" />
        <a href="#" onclick="document.setLangen.submit();return false;">English</a>
        </form>
    </li>

    <li>
        <form name="setLangde" action="/i18n/setlang/" method="POST"><div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='871Y71JyfG9WcieiKr8jjwe4j37IkIfq' /></div>
        <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/" />
        <input type="hidden" name="language" value="de" />
        <a href="#" onclick="document.setLangde.submit();return false;">Deutch</a>
        </form>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So here's the answer. I thought I'd write it down since someone else CAN end up in this situation.

The problem was that I had switched the order between django locale middleware and the middleware own my own that takes away the brwoser selected language. Need to keep your own interception before Django takes it over and sets the language to whatever the browser tells it to (which is a really weird default behavior in any case).

Hope it helps someone.

```
'myapp.middleware.ForceDefaultLanguageMiddleware',   # <-- BEFORE django locale!!
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
```

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that you keep language setting in the session, and when user logs out, session is gone and you're back to default lang.

Comment: No, that's just it. It never changes back. It goes to the second language installed, and stays there.